# Como pegar o nome que está no Resources para os nomes dos campos?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Quando eu tenho uma aplicação usando Resources, e na minha tela eu tenho um texto por exemplo:

```
<section>
    <div id="banner">
        <h1> 
            Com você, aonde você for!
            <small> dicas sempre atualizadas.</small>
        </h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

Como eu posso trocar este conteúdo através do Resources?
Eu consigo trocar apenas as opções do menu, desta forma:

```
<!--cabecalho do site-->
<header>

    <!--topo do site logotipo-->
    <div class="container">
        <img id="logotipo" src="~/Content/imagens/logo.png" alt="logotipo">
    </div>

    <!--topo do site linha do menu 01-->
    <div class="header-black">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="pull-right">
                <li class="espanhol"> <a href="/Home/AlteraIdioma/?LinguagemAbreviada=es"></a> </li>
                <li class="ingles">   <a href="/Home/AlteraIdioma/?LinguagemAbreviada=en"></a> </li>
                <li class="portugues"> <a href="/Home/AlteraIdioma/?LinguagemAbreviada=pt"></a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  <!--topo do site linha do menu 01-->
    <!--topo do site linha do menu 02-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <nav id="menu" class="pull-right">
                <ul>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Projeto.WebSite.Resources.HomeText.lojavirtual, "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Projeto.WebSite.Resources.HomeText.cadastro, "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Projeto.WebSite.Resources.HomeText.contalogin, "Index", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>      <!--topo do site linha do menu 02-->


</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só apontar pro *resources*, da mesma forma:

```
<section>
    <div id="banner">
        <h1> 
            @Projeto.WebSite.Resources.HomeText.TituloPrincipal
            <small> @Projeto.WebSite.Resources.HomeText.TituloSecundario</small>
        </h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: você foi genial agora, agradeço demais a ajuda!